# How to enumerate json string in MVC Razor foreach loop?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, enumeration

I'm using SQL Server 2016 to return json data in a string field in my data set. I passed the json string to the model without any conversions. I want to enumerate my json string field in MVC razor like:

```
 @foreach (var notification in Model.AccountSettings.EmailNotifications)
 {
```

EmailNotifications is a json array of objects.

```
EmailNotifications = [{"EmailNotificationID":8,"EmailNotificationName":"Any new KLAS report is published.","IsSet":false},{"EmailNotificationID":9,"EmailNotificationName":"KLAS publishes a report in one of my areas of interest.","IsSet":false}]
```

What the best way to do this?

Comment: My guess would be that would have to cast the object as an array or something. You'd probably also have to cast each item to something else. Why don't you want to use JSON.Net to convert it to an object?

Comment: So you have a list of `EmailNotification` class objects in `Model.AccountSettings.EmailNotifications` ? or is it just  a STRING ? How does your string  value looks like ?

Comment: yes it is just a string

Comment: Eonasdan - Is there a way to do it without creating an object and serializing it?

Comment: You could also use `FastJson`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean solution is to create a class to represent each item in your JSON array, convert your string to a list of this class and enumerate that.

```
public class NotificationItem
{
    public int EmailNotificationID { get; set; }
    public string EmailNotificationName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSet { get; set; }
}
```

And you may use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method to convert the json string to list of `NotificationItem` objects.

```
@{
    var items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                .DeserializeObject<List<NotificationItem>>("yourJsonStringHere");
}
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    <p>@item.EmailNotificationID</p>
    <p>@item.EmailNotificationName </p>
}
```